# How to check whether control is button or not?

Tags: c#, mouseevent

How can I check that whether mouse pointer is pointing a button or some other control?
I want to perform a particular task when mouse hover/move a button.

I know I can set event on individual button. But isn't it possible to check the pointed/hover control is button?

Comment: You are refering to WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean: can I do this without event handlers for `MouseHover` in individual controls. If so, the answer is no.

But you can attach each contol's MouseHover event to just one event handler that could look like the one in Chris's answer. For convenience you could even do that programmatically by looping through the controls in the form's load event. (assuming this is winforms)

Answer (score 12):

The sender argument in an event method should have the information you need...

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) {
   if(sender is Button) {
      //Do some stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're looking for then?  The code about is basically saying "If the source of the event is an instance of System.Windows.Forms.Button, do something."  If you want to know when the mouse is over a certain control, like a button, you could listen to MouseEnter, MouseHover, or MouseMove events for the controls (buttons) you care about.